# mysql check collation of a table

Tags: mysql, collation

How can I see what collation a table has? I.E. I want to see:

```
+-----------------------------+
|  table  |     collation     |
|-----------------------------|
| t_name  |  latin_general_ci |
+-----------------------------+
```

Answer (score 215, accepted):

[`SHOW TABLE STATUS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-table-status.html) shows information about a table, including the collation.

For example `SHOW TABLE STATUS where name like 'TABLE_NAME'`

Answer (score 84):

The above answer is great, but it doesn't actually provide an example that saves the user from having to look up the syntax:

`show table status like 'test';`

Where `test` is the table name.

(Corrected as per comments below.)

Answer (score 39):

**Checking the collation of a specific table**

You can query `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` and get the collation for a specific table:

```
SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA
    , TABLE_NAME
    , TABLE_COLLATION 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 't_name';
```

that gives a much more readable output in contrast to `SHOW TABLE STATUS` that contains a lot of irrelevant information.

---

**Checking the collation of columns**

Note that collation can also be applied to columns (which might have a different collation than the table itself). To fetch the columns' collation for a particular table, you can query `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`:

```
SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA 
    , TABLE_NAME 
    , COLUMN_NAME 
    , COLLATION_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 't_name';
```

---

For more details you can refer to the article [How to Check and Change the Collation of MySQL Tables](https://betterprogramming.pub/how-to-check-and-change-the-collation-of-mysql-tables-6095fada0ebd)

Comment: Works for mariaDB 10.4

Comment: Another option the worked for me on MariaDB:
`SELECT COLLATION_NAME 
FROM information_schema.columns 
WHERE TABLE_NAME = "__global_search" AND COLUMN_NAME = "name";`

Answer (score 10):

### Check collation of the whole database

If someone is looking here *also* for a way to check collation on the whole database:

1. `use mydatabase;` (where `mydatabase` is the name of the database you're going to check)
2. `SELECT @@character_set_database, @@collation_database;`

You should see the result like:

```
+--------------------------+----------------------+
| @@character_set_database | @@collation_database |
+--------------------------+----------------------+
| utf8mb4                  | utf8mb4_unicode_ci   |
+--------------------------+----------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 9):

Use this query:

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename
```

You will get all information related to table.

Comment: SHOW CREATE TABLE will not show collation. You have to use SHOW TABLE STATUS as described above.

Comment: Works for me in mysql 5.5.52. `...) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=24 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1` My guess is it may not show the collation if it is set to the default for the database in later versions of mysql/mariadb.

Comment: @DeveloperChris What you show is the charset, not the collation. Two tables may have the same charset `utf8`, but different collations `utf8_general_ci` vs `utf8_unicode_ci`. This can cause error messages like `HY000, 1267, Illegal mix of collations (utf8_general_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '='`... which is the message that brought me to this page.