# Django encoding error when querying the DB

Tags: django, encoding, neomodel

I am using the Neomodel library to bind my Neo4j database with Django framework. 
Trying to get an instance from my DB via local shell, I am getting an encoding error:

```
city = PlaceName.index.search(name=u'Zürich')

UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xfc' in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)
```

How can I avoid this?

Comment: You are sure that you have your table with correct encoding ? `utf-8` ?

Comment: PlaceName is a class:
   `class PlaceName(StructuredNode):
    name = StringProperty(index=True, required=True)
    lang = StringProperty(index=True, required=True)
    type = StringProperty(index=True, required=True)
    hasid = RelationshipTo('PlaceId', 'HAS_ID')
    descr = RelationshipTo('Desc', 'HAS_DESC')`

Comment: But it's about your database for example for MySQL http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3832056/mysql-check-collation-of-a-table

Comment: I use a graph-database, NoSQL, I don't have tables of this kind

Comment: But you still got to select some sort of encoding for your text data. If you didn't select I suggest you to look at the default encoding for that field and how to change it, to UTF8 preferably.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm ...

Can you please try this:

```
city = PlaceName.index.search(name=unicode('Zürich','utf-8'))
```

Comment: exactly the same error, but thank you for trying to help

Comment: Sorry mate ;/  I was doing my best.