# how can I save persian numbers in database (mysql)

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x

I'm developing a telegram bot with python.

I ask users to input their `phone numbers`. The problem is, if they enter `Persian numbers` (like `۰۶۰۷۵۰`), their data doesn't set in my database, and after updating database its field is empty!

But if they enter English digits, it saves in database?!

- python 3.7
- database: MySQL
- OS: win 10

Comment: What is the type of the column you're trying to insert those persian numbers?

Comment: What is the `collation` of your table?

Comment: nothing, I didn't determined it. it's empty

Comment: This post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3832056/mysql-check-collation-of-a-table/52479645#52479645 should advise how to get table's collation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convert to the string and save it later in the database

Use the number to convert the number to the number

database----> '۰۶۰۷۵۰'

using ---> get database-----> int('۰۶۰۷۵۰')

Comment: actually, you mean I should change type of field to text, am I right???

Answer (score 0):

thanks

I solved it without any change to my database!

```
phone_number = str(phone_number)
print('str:    ', phone_number)
print('str type:    ', type(phone_number))

phone_number = int(phone_number)
print('int:    ', phone_number)
print('int type:    ', type(phone_number))
```